# How to make macros that work with `match`?

Tags: racket

I'm trying to write something sorta like a finite state machine for a calculator I made using `racket/gui`, and I decided to use a mix of `case` and `match` to implement it. For a particular state and symbol, I'll perform some arbitrary code and return the next state of the machine. A simple example:

```
  (case current-state
    [(state-1)
     (match symbol
       [(? predicate-1?) 
        (some-action)
        next-state]
       [(? predicate-2?) 
        (some-action)
        next-state]
       ; ...
       )]
    ; ...
    )
```

I wanted to make this a little easier to read, though, and wanted to toy with macros. Some of the predicates I'll use often and would like to write them in shorter ways. And I don't like that the next state is lost at the end of a series of actions. I want that info front-and-center. So I'd prefer to write something like:

```
(case current-state
  [(state-1)
   (match symbol
     [:PRED-1: next-state
      (some-action)]
     [:PRED-2: next-state
      (some-action)]
     ; ...
     )]
  ; ...
  )
```

I'm not too experienced with macros, and my early attempts have all gone awry. My first partial attempt was just the predicate macros. Here's a simple example:

```
(define (in-list value lst)
  (if (list? (member value lst))
    #true
    #false))
(define (is-non-zero-digit? symbol)
  (in-list symbol '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)))
(define-syntax :NOT-0:
  #'(? is-non-zero-digit?))

(match 0
  [:NOT-0: 'wrong]
  [_ 'right])
; 'wrong
```

I'm not sure why that happens. I figured `:NOT-0:` would expand to `(? is-non-zero-digit?)`. Another thing I tried was to get the order that I wanted by defining a macro named `transition`:

```
; defined earlier in file
(define-syntax-rule
  (transition pattern next-state action ...)
  [pattern action ... next-state])
; ...
; the below is from a rackunit test
(define a-variable 0)
(define (side-effect)
  (set! a-variable 1))
(define result
  (match 0
    (transition (? is-non-zero-digit?) 'wrong (side-effect))
    [_ 'right]))
(check-equal? result 'right)
(check-equal? a-variable 1))
```

But I get the error `state-machine.rkt:220:21: ?: unbound identifier`. I'd like answers to provide me with a way to get the desired form, and would appreciate an explanation as to why my earlier attempts didn't work out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's first talk about why your `:NOT-0:` doesn't work. First of all, a macro is a syntax object transformer. That is, a function from syntax object to syntax object. So you need to write:

```
(define-syntax :NOT-0:
  (lambda (stx) #'(? is-non-zero-digit?)))
```

or use its shorthand form:

```
(define-syntax (:NOT-0: stx)
  #'(? is-non-zero-digit?))
```

But the corrected code doesn't quite work either. The reason is that Racket macros by default are expanded "outside in". That means:

```
(define-syntax-rule (foo (#:foo x))
  x)

(define-syntax-rule (bar x)
  (#:foo x))

(foo (bar 1)) ; doesn't work, because `foo` is expanded first, and it couldn't find #:foo
```

Most macros that want to let users extend the its functionality like `foo` will provide a "macro defining macros" that you can use to define `bar` in a way that `foo` understands that `bar` should be expanded first. For technical details, see [Macros that Work Together](https://www.cs.utah.edu/plt/publications/jfp12-draft-fcdf.pdf) by Matthew Flatt et al.

For your particular problem, Racket's `match` provides [`define-match-expander`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fmatch..rkt%29._define-match-expander%29%29) which is a macro defining macros I described above. You can use it like this:

```
(define-match-expander :NOT-0:
  ;; can also use syntax-case on stx to further ensure that stx must have a particular shape.
  (lambda (stx) #'(? is-non-zero-digit?)))

(define (is-non-zero-digit? symbol)
  ;; no need to define in-list. member alone would suffice
  (member symbol '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)))

(match 0
  [(:NOT-0:) 'wrong]
  [_ 'right])
```

Notice that you need parentheses around `:NOT-0:`. If you have a bare `:NOT-0:`, `match` would treat it as an identifier to bind the matching value to.

---

Personally, I don't find Racket's `match` to be appropriate here. Usually, when there are a lot of `(? predicate)` clauses, it suggests that you should convert it to `cond` instead:

```
(cond
  [(predicate-1? symbol) ...]
  [(predicate-2? symbol) ...]
  ...)
```

Finally, you could create your own `match` if you really want it to be in the form that you want. And you can expand your `match` to `cond` or Racket's `match` however you want. As a bonus, you will have a complete control over the subforms in it, allowing you to swap "action" and "state". Here's a small example.

```
(define-syntax-rule (match e [pred e*] ... [#:else e-else])
  (let ([v e]) ; so that we evaluate e only once
    (cond [(pred v) e*] ... [else e-else])))

(match 0
  [is-non-zero-digit? 'wrong]
  [#:else 'right])

(require (only-in racket/match [match r:match]))
;; Racket's match is still available via r:match
```

Comment: I was using match in the hopes of avoiding creating a whole new form. I was hoping to just @sorawee create a macro I could drop into an existing form. I figured if I tried to use something like `:NOT-0:` with `cond`, then I'd have to have it expand to include `symbol`, and I have some knowledge that this wouldn't work well. I think it goes against 'hygiene'... not that I'm clear on what this means.

Comment: What is the `#:foo` in your example foo macro? Is it like an optional argument as in lambdas? Or are you specifying the pattern `(#:foo x)`? If it is the latter, I am confused, I thought that a pattern has to start with the `id` given in the syntax rule.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean by "outside in", but not entirely. I extracted just enough from my program to use `:NOT-0:` and run it through the macro stepper. While I don't fully understand what happens, it seems that `:NOT-0:` wouldn't get expanded until `match` was fully expanded first. Sounds like what you mean by 'outside in'.

Comment: Yep. Outside in means exactly that. The outer macro will get expanded first.

Comment: `#:foo` is a keyword. It is usually used in lambda for keyword argument, but it can be used in syntax in general too. For instance, in the `for` syntax, you can do something like `(for ([x 10] #:when (odd? x)) (displayln x))`.

Comment: So in the above example, `(define-syntax-rule (foo (#:foo x)) x)` is equivalent to `(define-syntax (foo stx) ... extract content of stx, make sure that it has #:foo at the first position, and return the content of the second position ...)`. So if you call `(foo (#:foo 1))`, it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Following @sorawee advice, I made my own macro, if anyone is interested in my final result:

```
(define-syntax-rule 
  (transition to-evaluate
                 [pred next-symbol body ... ] ... 
                 [#:else else-next-symbol else-body ...])
  (let ([v to-evaluate])
    (cond 
      [(pred v) body ... next-symbol] ... 
      [else else-body ... else-next-symbol])))
```

It will transform expressions like:

```
(transition symbol
  [is-digit?  '1st-operand
    (send accumulator-register push symbol)]
  [is-operator?  'got-op
    (set! current-operator symbol)]
  [#:else (clear-calculator)])
```

to

```
(cond
  [(is-digit? symbol)
   (send accumulator-register push symbol)
   '1st-operand]
  [(is-operator? symbol)
    (set! current-operator symbol)
    'got-op]
  [else (clear-calculator)])
```